# How can I repair Mr. Handy?

Tags: fallout-shelter

My Mr. Handy has been busy trying to solo deathclaws, mole rats, and such. Now he is a bit worse for wear. How can I repair him?

[image: Mr. Handy got rekt]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is unfortunately **no way** to repair it when it's partially damaged ; you have to wait until he "dies", then you can "revive" him - for 2,000 caps.

---

*Disclaimer: the following might not be accurate anymore.*

<s>Here's a nice tip to optimize your Mr. Handy usage I found in [this article](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/fallout-shelter-game-tips-tricks-mr-handy-%E2%80%93-how-get-use-and-repair-new-robotic-butler-468677) :</s>

> When he gets near the end of his life, it might be a good idea to send him into the wastelands. Or even better, set him out in the Wastelands at night when you go to bed so he has several hours to gather caps. That way you can repair him ASAP.

Comment: seems that the "wastelands autorepair" isn't working anymore (v1.11 on steam) anyone can confirm this?

Comment: What do you mean, “autorepair”?

Comment: you said: `set him out in the Wastelands at night when you go to bed so he has several hours` but seems not to be working anymore

Comment: What does it do then? You send him, and he just dies, w/o gathering any caps?

Comment: he just survives with the same HP and returns with the caps that has collected, might be a fixed bug?

Comment: Well, no, that's the point of this tip. When you feel Mr. Handy is about to die, you might as well send him away and let him collect some caps, so when he actually dies you can revive him ASAP.

Comment: 7h 55m = 155 caps... http://i.imgur.com/Lpy6BSs.png

Comment: Maybe it has been changed then.

Answer (score 6):

You unfortunately can't heal him however I did read that you can revive him for 2000 caps

[How to heal/revive and use Mr.Handy](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/fallout-shelter-game-tips-tricks-mr-handy-%E2%80%93-how-get-use-and-repair-new-robotic-butler-468677)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to heal/repair Mr.Handy,but if you have multiple Mr.Handy's when one gets hurt you can switch him out with one from a lower level that way it's less likely to get hurt by raiders or Deathclaws and die.