# How can Mr Handy survive?

Tags: fallout-shelter

It has been [previously noted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/233068/108003) that there's no way to repair Mr Handy. You need to revive him after he dies, instead.

On survival mode, you can't revive dwellers. Can you revive Mr Handy? Is there some other way to keep him around on survival mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put it simply, YES you can revive Mr. Handy in survival. I've done it multiple times.  There's a bug that makes the button disappear. (saw this bug 2 or 3 times) You just have to close the game all the way and load the app back up.  I am not sure if they patched the bug yet.

Comment: Alright, I'll let him die and see what happens then.

Comment: I was able to revive Mr Handy on survival for a couple thousand caps. I didn't see the bug.